# How to deploy a VM/App gateway referring to another Vnet which is not in the VM/App gateway's resource group through Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Example:

Consider the below scenario:

Resource group: A-> VM

Resource group: B-> Vnet

I want to create a VM which is in Resource group A by referring the Vnet to Resource group B. I want to achieve this by Azure ARM template.

Can some one help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Nested Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) or take a look at this [quickstart template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-different-rg-vnet)